# DIV not displaying Horizontal Scrollbar

Tags: php, css, html, scrollbars

I'm trying to get my DIV to display *only* a horizontal scrollbar. I am filling up the DIV with lots of images, and only want the user to be able to scrol horizontally.

But I have two problems:

One tutorial I read gave me some code (which I no longer have), that says it will display the scrollbar. But it didn't. And it also made the images appear beneath each other. So I scrapped that code.

Another tutorial gave me the 'look' that I wanted, *but without the scrollbars*. But the scrollbars were supposed to appear!

How can I have a DIV, full of pics and a Horizontal Scrollbar?

Here's what I have so far:

CSS: (dude.css)

```
.EditorialImagePaneOne
{
    width: 500px

    -ms-overflow-x:scroll;
      overflow-x:scroll;
    white-space:nowrap;

}

.ShowcaseImage
{
    height: 407px;
}
```

HTML: (Index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Assets/CSS/dude.css" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="EditorialImagePaneOne">
        <img src="../Assets/Images/Editorial/1-1.jpg" class="ShowcaseImage" />
        <img src="../Assets/Images/Editorial/1-2.jpg" class="ShowcaseImage" />
        <img src="../Assets/Images/Editorial/1-3.jpg" class="ShowcaseImage" />
        <img src="../Assets/Images/Editorial/1-4.jpg" class="ShowcaseImage" />
        <img src="../Assets/Images/Editorial/1-5.jpg" class="ShowcaseImage" />
        <img src="../Assets/Images/Editorial/1-6.jpg" class="ShowcaseImage" />
        <img src="../Assets/Images/Editorial/1-7.jpg" class="ShowcaseImage" />
        <img src="../Assets/Images/Editorial/1-8.jpg" class="ShowcaseImage" />
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are missing a semicolon in your CSS. Is that a typo or a copy-paste of your code?

Comment: The code you posted works [just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/us4rA/) on Chrome 13, IE 9 and FF 3.6 so please explain what exactly is wrong.

Comment: @Henrik - Sorry just a copy-paste typo. It's got the semicolon in the actual code file.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - The code is obviously **not** fine as it does not display a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @Paul yes it does, see the jsFiddle and [this](http://i.imgur.com/j21hx.gif) screenshot.

Comment: I can see from the Fiddle you linked to that it works there. But using the exact same code in my webpage (which currently only consists of the code shown above, so there's nothing else causing this problem) still doesn't work, not in a single browser.

Comment: No, it really doesn't. The exact same code does not work on my page - therefor it doesn't work.

Comment: @Paul so something else in the page is messing things up.. can you post a link?

Comment: OK, see my answer maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Well, that's the thing. There is nothing else on the page. :( It's just the usual <html><head><body> stuff and that DIV with images inside, there's nothing else at all (yet).

Comment: I used this code and everything seems fine. http://pastebin.com/8s2dULut

Comment: Can you post your *entire* page source, as a pastebin/similar? Also what browser are you testing in? The code provided clearly works, as proved by several users, so the problem must lay elsewhere

Comment: I am using IE 7/8/9, Safari, Firefox, Maxthon, Chrome, RockMelt, Flock (Dead), Opera 11, and Epic. There's really no other code to post, so I'll just update this question to show what's left.

Comment: I just posted the entire source of my HTML and CSS Files. :)

Comment: @Paul use the `@` to notify people when you reply to comments otherwise they won't get notified and might not come back to see the reply.. e.g. @Ross will notify Ross you posted the entire code.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard; I just had to restart my PC after downloading Windows Updates. After restarting, I reopened WebMatrix and opened the site again, and ran it in the browser (IE9), and now it works like a charm. With horizontal scrollbars! Woot! *confused look on face*

Comment: @Paul really weird indeed! Guess one of those Windows mysterious bugs nobody will ever solve! :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you miss something like the `DOCTYPE` in the page.. make sure to have this as the very first line in your code, above the `<html>` line:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: Hmm. I am currently using: `<!DOCTYPE html>` since it's an HTML5 based website. But I'll give it a go, to see.

Comment: So it should work - do you by any chance view the HTML by double clicking it? It's not good, you should view it as web page hosted on some server.

Comment: Thanks for the Doctype bit. I just tried it, but it didn't make any difference. That scrollbar still refuses to appear.

Comment: Nah, I use WebMatrix, has its own little server thing in there. I like it because I'm on an extremely limited internet plan atm and it lets me test any site even if I'm not online. I haven't had any problems with any other site. It's just this one thing that won't work, and I've done this months ago. I don't get why it won't work.

Comment: @Paul that's very weird. Give it a try using something like local IIS if possible.

Comment: @Shadow W, Ummm, local IIS.. I have IIS installed. I tried it with Abyss Web Server, and went to localhost, and that didn't work either, still no scrollbar. Will try local iis now.