# How do you add a scrollbar for paging in PHP?

Tags: php, html, scrollbar

I have a lot of images stored in database, and want to display those images on the page, three per row.

I'd like to use a scrollbar for listing those images instead of paging through them. So instead of Next/Previous buttons, I'd like to use a scroll bar to display the images ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the div height for the div that will hold all the images, then set `overflow-y: scroll;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Ajax, and jQuery may simplify your life, check this awesome tutorial, it may solve your problem:
http://www.bewebdeveloper.com/tutorial-about-ajax-scroll-paging-using-jquery-php-and-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.

If you want to display all the images, get them all from the database and print the HTML for each one. If you want to do rows, use the `mod` http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php operator and a count variable to determine how many images you've counted through and whether or not you need a new row (to get the 3 images per row)

Comment: yes i want to display all the images on same page by limiting 3 images per row...but here instead of using paging comcept i want to add scrollbar for listing the images...hope now im clear

Comment: @vvv I think what we don't understand is 'add a scrollbar'. Do you know of an example of what you're looking for that's somewhere online?

Comment: If you put all images on a page, in rows of 3, the browser will display the scollbar if required. What else do you want?

Answer (score 0):

One link to look at is [here](http://pear.php.net/package/Gtk_Styled/docs/latest/Gtk_Styled/_Gtk_Styled-1.0.0---ScrollBar.php.html), and [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=209153), but it'd probably be easier to do this in [CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402230/div-not-displaying-horizontal-scrollbar).